# How do you add a Scatter trace to a plotly figure that consists only of markers and that connects the markers of two other Scatter traces?

Tags: python, plotly

I am currently trying set up a plot that consists of multiple traces, one "base" trace, and then another trace that is situated on top of the base trace. Each of these traces consist only of markers.

However, what I would like to do is connect the markers together using a line

Here is a very basic reconstruction of the code I am currently using:

```
url = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data'
iris_df = pd.read_csv(url,header=None,encoding='utf-8')
iris_df.columns = ['sepal length','sepal width','petal length', 'petal width', 'class']

test_fig =  go.Figure()

class_colors = {'Iris-setosa':'blue', 'Iris-versicolor':'green', 'Iris-virginica':'purple'}

for group in iris_df['class'].unique():
    iris_df_class = iris_df[iris_df['class']==group]
    test_fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=iris_df_class['sepal length'],
                                 y= iris_df_class['petal length'],
                                 mode='markers',
                                 marker=dict(size=10, color=class_colors[group], symbol=1),
                                 name='trace1 '+group,
                                 showlegend=True,
                                 legendgroup=group))

    test_fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=iris_df_class['sepal length'],
                                 y= iris_df_class['petal length']+0.5,
                                 mode='markers',
                                 marker=dict(size=10, color='red', symbol=5),
                                 name='trace2',
                                 showlegend=False,
                                 legendgroup=group))

    test_fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=iris_df_class['sepal length'],
                                 y= iris_df_class['petal length']+0.2,
                                 mode='markers',
                                marker_line_width = 2,
                                 marker=dict(size=20, color='black', symbol=42),
                                 name='trace-intermediate',
                                 showlegend=False,
                                 legendgroup=group))

test_fig.show()
```

So for the trace named 'trace-intermediate', I have its marker symbol set to 42, which is just a line (as dictated by https://plotly.com/python/marker-style/#custom-marker-symbols). I want this line to connect the markers of trace1 and trace2. However, when I zoom in on one or more particular markers within the figure, the line marker of 'trace-intermediate' decreases in size proportionally and stops connecting its pertinent markers of the other traces. How can I amend this? I would prefer the markers to be connected with this line so that it can be included in the same legendgroup as the two other traces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have realized is a line connecting a square marker and a triangle marker with a line marker, but it does not correspond to zooming, so I have come up with a solution with the understanding that there is a way to solve this problem. I would add a new loop process to the data extracted by class in line mode for scatter plots to draw a line from the square markers to the triangle markers.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

url = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data'
iris_df = pd.read_csv(url,header=None,encoding='utf-8')
iris_df.columns = ['sepal length','sepal width','petal length', 'petal width', 'class']

test_fig =  go.Figure()

class_colors = {'Iris-setosa':'blue', 'Iris-versicolor':'green', 'Iris-virginica':'purple'}

for group in iris_df['class'].unique():
    iris_df_class = iris_df[iris_df['class']==group]
    test_fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=iris_df_class['sepal length'],
                                  y= iris_df_class['petal length'],
                                  mode='markers',
                                  marker=dict(size=10, color=class_colors[group], symbol=1),
                                  name='trace1 '+group,
                                  showlegend=True,
                                  legendgroup=group))

    test_fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=iris_df_class['sepal length'],
                                  y= iris_df_class['petal length']+0.5,
                                  mode='markers',
                                  marker=dict(size=10, color='red', symbol=5),
                                  name='trace2',
                                  showlegend=False,
                                  legendgroup=group))
    for s,p in zip(iris_df_class['sepal length'], iris_df_class['petal length']):
        test_fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[s,s],
                                      y=[p,p+0.5],
                                      mode='lines',
                                      marker_line_width = 2,
                                      line_color='black',
                                      #marker=dict(size=20, color='black', symbol=42),
                                      name='trace-intermediate',
                                      showlegend=False,
                                      legendgroup=group))

test_fig.update_layout(height=600)
test_fig.show()
```

[image]

[image]